# Reading frames not from the beginning of a video

Tags: c#, video, streaming, frames, aforge

The question is - does **FFPMEG** library from **AForge** framework allow to read video frames starting not from the beginning of a video?

Here is the example code provided by documentation:

```
VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
reader.Open("test.avi");

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();

    // process the frame somehow
    // dispose the frame when it is no longer required

    videoFrame.Dispose( );
}

reader.Close();
```

Link to docs: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/ffmpeg.html

The frames are being read when the video starts.

**If AForge doest not allow to do this**, could you recommend **FREE** library that will help with this situation?

Comment: For library recommendation, try asking at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Accord Framework](http://accord-framework.net), do not sure much it allows to jump forward in file read. Try to investigate [Accord VideoFileReader Class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Video_FFMPEG_VideoFileReader.htm)